# SQL PowerShell Cmdlets How to Install Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm interested in using SQL cmdlets to connect to app server databases on our network in order to read views and process data into Active Directory. Does someone know if these are available for use without buying the full SQL license? I think our company would let me install a fully licensed version of SQL Server, but I was curious if perhaps installing a trial and letting it expire, would still allow use of the cmdlets since I only use PowerShell for my automation tasks and wouldn't actually be using SQL on my scripting server? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running PowerShell version 5 or later you can install the official SQL module SqlServer from the PowerShell Gallery by running the command `Install-Module -Name SqlServer` with admin rights or `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser` if you do not.

Comment: I am running 5.0. Awesome! Thank you!